# What is the mimumum bend radius for 6 mm Medite Tricoya Extreme MDF?

Tags: mdf, bending

What is the minimum radius that 6 mm  [Medite Tricoya Extreme](https://mdfosb.com/en/medite/products/medite-tricoya-extreme) MDF (an MDF for outdoor use) can be bent to? If possible I want to bend it to a radius of 2500 mm, without [kerfing](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kerfing).

It will be fixed with screws over the whole surface, so it doesn't matter if it wants to spring back. What I'm interested in is if it is likely to crack when I bend it.

I will use painted [Medite Tricoya Extreme](https://mdfosb.com/en/medite/products/medite-tricoya-extreme) as the surface layer of a skateboard ramp. The manufacturer doesn't publish bendability data, and I haven't got hold of them to ask. The material is very expensive, so it would be great to hear if anyone has experience with this.

Comment: I think this is a case where you are going to have to create your own set of empirical evidence based on your material and methods. Set up some test pieces and give it a try. Not all "MDF" is created equal. In fact, different MDF is made differently precisely to offer various strength and stiffness.

Comment: Yes absolutely what @jdv said. We think of MDF as being a consistent material, and it is to a great extent within the one product, but across the class it varies hugely, with the better examples being notably less friable, heavier and generally stiffer (in addition to having greater resistance to water). So do a test — cut a narrow strip and see if it'll make the bend. If you have the spare material, cut one strip from the length, a second along the width.

Comment: What's the application? Perhaps HDF (hardboard) would be a better choice here anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your input! It would have been better to ask for the bend radius for Medite Tricoya Extreme, since that's what I'll use (for a skateboard ramp). But if I edit the question now your comments would be useless :/ Sounds good to do a test bend anyhow.

Comment: Skateboard ramps are sufficiently their own thing, and sufficiently not really "woodworking" that I think you have to find someone with that domain knowledge or figure it out yourself. You might just have better luck doing a web search for "MDF skateboard ramp bend" and seeing what collected wisdom the unwashed internet has. I'm not sure any site focused on woodworking will have this specific knowledge (mostly for the same reasons already discussed ).

Comment: @PetaspeedBeaver BTW, always feel free to [edit] your question if you want. Comments are ephemeral, and intended for a way for us to ask for clarification. We abuse comments a bit more in WW that other SE sites, but that's the way it goes sometimes.

Comment: "I haven't got hold of them to ask" I'd suggest that you probably should. They'll know better than anyone. You might manage to find someone, somewhere on the interwebz who has bent this stuff, but asking the manufacturer will be the fastest way to get a _quality_ answer. It may even be something they've never tested, but would be willing to do!

Comment: @FreeMan, yea, you're right. Sent several messages, but no answer for several weeks. I'll call them and post the info here if I get it.

Comment: Sorry to hear they're not responding to email. Please do post an answer if you get one from the company _or_ if you determine one via some testing of your own.

Comment: Did you ever the answer to this - considering Tricoya for my skate ramp but can't see anyone else that has done it yet.

Comment: Hey @chris, no, unfortunately no answer. I've been trying to reach Medite (the Irish manufacturer of Tricoya Extreme in Europe) through the forms on their website + e-mail for several months and they don't reply. Also no answer from Tricoya. I'll try to get some info from my dealer before I decide. Hopefully they will have same contact channel to Medite or a distributor that has.